# Getting an id's value in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I have been lumbered with a Ruby, Watir IE test program which I need to change.
It currently does this:-

```
browser.frame(:id,"ultraposuidialoghtm0").div(:class," content").button(:id,"ok").click
```

This issue I have is the first div ID can change, 0, 1, 2 etc.

How do I create a var that shows me the ID on the page?.

i.e. `my = browser.frame(:id)`

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: What's "the first div"? Did you mean to say that the id of the frame may change? Do you want to loop through a number of frames?

Comment: Yes the id of the frame can change depending on how many IE sessions you have open.  A for loop would be cool or a wildcard, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the html around the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try this, but judging from the documentation you should be able to do it using a regex:

```
browser.frames(:id, /ultraposuidialoghtm/).each do |frame|
  id = frame.id
  # do whatever
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, going to use $ultrapos.frame(:id, /ultraposuidialoghtm[0-9]*/) regex, seems to work for me.